# What was the reason for Gandhi's visit to Africa

Tags: india, south-africa

Why did Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi visit South Africa? What was the purpose of his visit to South Africa?

Comment: He didn't "visit" South Africa, he migrated there to work as a lawyer for Dada Abdullah & Co., a Muslim Indian trading firm operating in South Africa at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dada Abdulla and Sons in South Africa needed a lawyer who could speak Gujarati to settle a dispute:

> Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (his birth name) arrived in South Africa in 1893 at the relatively tender age of 24 as a newly qualified lawyer on a temporary assignment to act on behalf of a local Indian trader in a commercial dispute. What was meant to be a short stopgap for the struggling young lawyer turned into a 21-year stay, with spells in India and England.

Reference:
http://gandhi.southafrica.net